# GLFW window only updates when moved with the mouse?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I have two uniform in my shader and i am updating these uniform in my window loop but the window do no get updated with loop instead i have to use my mouse to update the window..
I have upload a vedio to showcase this problem https://youtu.be/jWABZ50HhCE

This is my code::

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include<gl\glew.h>
#include<GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<SOIL.h>

#include<glm/glm.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
//////////////////////////////////////
static const char* vertexShaderSource = "\n\
    #version 150 core\n\
    in vec2 position;\n\
    in vec3 inColor;\n\
    uniform mat4 trans;\n\      ////////////Uniform1/////////////
    in vec2 texcoord;\n\
    out vec2 Texcoord;\n\
    out vec3 Color;\n\
    void main(){\n\
        Color=inColor;\n\
        Texcoord=texcoord;\n\
        gl_Position=trans*vec4(position,0,1);\n\
    }\n";

static const char* fragmentShaderSource = "\n\
    #version 150 core\n\
    in vec3 Color;\n\
    in vec2 Texcoord;\n\
    uniform sampler2D te0;\n\  
    uniform sampler2D tex1;\n\ 
    out vec4 color;\n\
    uniform float mixvalue;\n\  ////////////Uniform2/////////////
    void main(){\n\
        vec4 color1=texture(te0,Texcoord);\n\
        vec4 color2=texture(tex1,Texcoord);\n\
        color=mix(color1,color2,mixvalue);\n\
    }\n\
    ";
//////////////////////////////////////
int main() {
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 620, "Window", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        return -1;

    GLfloat triangleVertices[] = {
        0.5f,0.5f,1,0,0,1,0,
        0.5f,-0.5f,0,1,0,1,1,
        -0.5f,-0.5f,0,0,1,0,1,
        -0.5f,0.5f,0,0,0,0,0
    };

    GLuint vao; 
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo); 
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangleVertices), triangleVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint elements[] = { 0,1,2 ,3,0,2};
    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    GLint statusVertex;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &statusVertex);
    if (!statusVertex) {
        char buffer[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 1024, NULL, buffer);
        std::cout << "Error Compiling vertexShader:" << buffer << std::endl;
    }



    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    GLint statusFrag;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &statusFrag);
    if (!statusFrag) {
        char buffer[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 1024, NULL, buffer);
        std::cout << "Error Compiling fragmentShader:" << buffer << std::endl;
    }

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(program, 0, "color");
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glUseProgram(program);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    GLint positionAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);

    GLint colorAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(program, "inColor");
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorAttrib);

    GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(program, "texcoord");
    glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)(5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);

    GLuint textures[2];
    glGenTextures(2, textures);
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* image;

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    image = SOIL_load_image("1.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "te0"), 0);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
    image = SOIL_load_image("2.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex1"), 1);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    GLuint mixvalue = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mixvalue");
        GLint uniTrans = glGetUniformLocation(program, "trans");
    //////These Two uniform/////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    float a=0,b=0;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        b += 3;
        trans = glm::rotate(trans, glm::radians(b), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniTrans, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(trans));

        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_E)) {
            break;
        }
        if (a >= 1) a = 0;
        a += 0.1f;
        glUniform1f(mixvalue, a);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong here.Is there something that i am doing wrong or is it because of some driver error.
GlfwVersion 3.3.0 32 bit

Comment: Try to minimize your code sample to still have the problem in it but keep it as short as possible.

Comment: Does this code even compile? There are several \ missing in the shader strings.

Comment: Then, there are several \n missing too, especially after ////////////Uniform1///////////// and  ////////////Uniform2/////////////. But after fixing all of this, the program works as expected for me.

Comment: @Abhisek: If you want to take videos of your screen, use OBS: https://obsproject.com/

Comment: You aren't running this under a "weird" environment like a virtual machine or over VNC/remote desktop, right?  What does your GL implementation report for `GL_RENDERER` & `GL_VENDOR`?

Comment: If you insist on embedding shaders directly in the source, consider using raw strings rather than \ all over the place. You also shouldn't have to include explicit `\n`s as the shader compiler doesn't care about them except for preprocessor directives, etc.

Comment: The rotation speeds up rapidly, because the angle is incremented, and the new rotation matrix is multiplied to the rotation matrix of the previous frame. Either use a constant angle or increment the angle and do `glm::mat4 trans = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(b), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));` in the main application loop.

Comment: @Rabbid76 no this issue is not because of rotation because even if you remove rotation uniform and only keep mixvalue uniform then also the same problem.exist.

Comment: @genpfault no I am not running on any virtual environment.My GL_RENDERER is Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 and GL_VENDOR is Intel.

Comment: @BDL the program compiles. those \n were removed by mistake..

Comment: @Abhishek Of course this is not the major issue. I just mentioned that there is another bug. But your issue is not reproducible, there is nothing obvious in this code which causes that behavior, your program works fine for me.